# How to compare Karate Test Results between two Environments?

Tags: unit-testing, automated-tests, cucumber, karate, web-api-testing

I have two different Environments (Say) `QA` and `QA2` Setup for Karate API Testing.

I wanted to know if it is possible to run Tests on both for same feature files and have a comparative result. Like How many Tests are failing on `QA` vs `QA2`.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very specific need which is more a responsibility of your continuous integration and 3rd party reporting than Karate (in my opinion).

You can look at this thread for ideas on 3rd party report servers etc: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/619

You can probably take the JSON report files (or the `Results` data mentioned in the above thread) and write your own custom solution which might be the best approach.